# Xamarin forms - How to read data from built in credit card reader in Android POS device?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an Android application using Xamarin-forms. The application must run on point of sale devices which have a built in magnetic card reader. So, how can I read data from the card and set the value in entry field?

Comment: How is the data coming out of the card reader?

Comment: or how to read card number from the card reader ?

Comment: Check with the manufacturer, they probably have an SDK you can hit to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Check with the manufacturer of the device to see if they or the card-reader manufacturer have an SDK you can use to get this data out.

Comment: i want it as general as possible so the application can works in every point of sale android device what ever the manufacturer .. is it possible  ?

Comment: Note that the prototype application from the manufacturer  is reading the Card data without any problems

Comment: This will not work, as different android POS devices are going to use different SDKs. Some may have some components in common or subscribe to a common standard, either way you HAVE to go through their systems.

Of course the prototype of their reader reads fine, it is using their SDK to get the data, which is what you should be doing.

Something I have done when different (but similar) systems existed. In this case it was eWay, PayPal and PayWay. I made my own library as a wrapper around the  SDKs, that  way when I call my library, it simply interprets the call and uses the correct SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If the device is based on NFC ,maybe you can try using NFC reader to read the data.

Here is a Android sample , you can try:

https://github.com/poz1/NFCForms

And here are some discussions about NFC Reader:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussions/tagged/nfc-reader/p1